# Deploying Huge ML Models

Tags: django, machine-learning

I am trying to deploy couple of RF Classification Model in Ubuntu 16.04 using Django framework and Gunicorn+Nginx. There around 5-6 models each around 800MB-1.2GB pickled size. But my development machine has only 8GB of RAM and I am not able to run other dependent services due to Out of Memory error.

I have to load these models at startup since unpickling on every single request would take time and it has to be a synchronous call with a acceptable response time(within 30 sec). I had a look a Django FileSystem Cache but I am not sure if that would help(suspect it to be also pickling and loading).

I would need suggestions how to deploy such models in Dev machines in optimized manner.

Comment: can you break the model in different parts?

Comment: Do you need all data in the model for every request?

Comment: We have already broken the model considering the class balance. Features had been selected from the sample after doing PCA.